# Is there a way to get VSCode to display addition intellisense information about JavaScript functions from their comment lines?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Visual Studio Code provides displays useful hover-over information about a function in a JavaScript module, like this:

[image]

Is there a way to get it also display a comment line above the function so that one can have additional information about the function displayed, e.g. examples of how to use the function?

[image]

I remember this was possible in NetBeans with PHPDoc, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JS-Doc format. Then it should work. https://jsdoc.app/

```
/**
 * Some comment
 */
export const replaceAll = (text: string, search: string, replace: string) => {
    return text.split(search).join(replace);
};
```

Comment: Works perfectly out-of-the-box, no install. Even multi-line comments show up nicely. Thanks.

Comment: Works in VSCode without adding any extensions, thanks! Just format your comment like this:  `/** Comment */ `